# Acer Aspire 43 graphical glitch with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04, suspend, freeze, visual-artifacts

When I put my Ubuntu 22.04 into sleep mode and attempt to turn the device again, the screen shows an unknown glitch, and the device freezes (the glitch begins at responding to commands, and then the screen is on with several blocks of cubes).

I perform a force power-off that can damage the SSD when this glitch happens.

- CPU: Ryzen 3200U
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 fresh installation

[System information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61TQv.png)